# Can I decrypt RSA, without private key and with phi(n)?

Tags: rsa

I tried to solve it with before questions, but I could see garbled text.

> N = 128460239683165454397359459447210283044155022502286524838891741988679938193570963279804482568371971887759551279983208141902250908464433446323394446692749134904325345980971971109380664499324457465544602291674241349010997748225039112587326923593916949633374423858327627496691319520844119255578585288814292147521
>
> E = 65537
>
> C = 12980952351506680501768608140422982425679045413809355260637023829663466481251357366568945448811230472008822859914518680654182673545034780034586273565467876672269015273032818970022854810626295056834531528305728579664376946838556395868262468392549876936613591881438492372150411237863927418884554317237849919293
>
> phi(N) = 128460239683165454397359459447210283044155022502286524838891741988679938193570963279804482568371971887759551279983208141902250908464433446323394446692749112111956538551945593442649939415468923449335794817997960771958187394162899871879485986038558028982196479712555097533192792450911799622278696104620413626544

Comment: Just follow the RSA key generation process to compute d using the extended euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following:

> M =
>   29601594434437796422434939577857054663831379044762263768915745056794939858621563434464066878271051039602545412162191910512922410514405275920053976044300439862908797747326760027555250453098438166908227474239886834293225796342063897315533373952881916686247287367936046664248440704422361259858606007022579187404
>
> D =
>   69486175698738351746134135486879236674173299780369215947307814722961133542305730324382698430638973456537163630855924571317496905642067315747811665704227474928191087350145281101392196046178087740954787773288794259211098205945874856312125642081066910713320188684408474717360948660830115760711960829894466683873

I figured out that d can be extracted from e and phiN by passing them through the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279208/rsa-calculate-d/23280454#23280454). From there, it was just the matter of doing C^d mod N. The math checks out on my side.